# Show off your Character Sheet Designs

Tags: character-sheets

<sup>**Notice:** This thread has a associated [meta-thread](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/show-off-character-sheet-thread), If you want to discuss if it is on topic please do so there.</sup>

This is a chance to show off the great character sheets you have created.

#### Rules:

- 1 Character sheet per answer
- Only character sheets you have designed.

  - This means you are welcome to post Professional Sheets, if you are the professional who created them
  - You are welcome to post sheets that you created for a RPG that you did not create. (Eg your customised dnd 3.5 sheet)

#### Post should contain:

- Image of character sheet (screen capture is fine for electronic sheets)

  - Resize to the Large Thumbnail size (max size in any dimension of 1024), by adding `l` to the url before the file extension (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow))
  - Preferably only a single image.
- a link to a  full version of the sheet (so it can be viewed at its full glory)

  - For sheets made for printing, a pdf is great
  - For others this might be a downloadable excel file or a website to view.
  - If this is impossible, describe as such in your post.
- A paragraph describing how it was made.
- A paragraph describing what makes it good.

Answer (score 10):

I re-edited and translated from Italian to English, the marvellous DnD 3.5 sheet made by Dragon's Lair (Udine), whose original sheet (in Italian) is linked [here](http://www.dragonslair.it/forum/downloads.php?do=file&id=49).

[image: Screenshot of the first page only.]

*How it was made*: with Openoffice. (after failing with LaTex for a while)

*What is good about it*: it has everything. The first page has all the combat-related stuff one needs, with enough columns that one remembers where a modifier came from. It has a big enough HP box, it has all the melee and ranged fields so that newbies can be pointed to the rights stuff they need. All the things that can have a temp modifier have a temp column to keep track of these things, there are projectiles or "countable" ammos in the bottom. The following pages contain all the relevant info for a character, with aid so not to violate some rules (e.g. it has body slots for magic items so that one does not wear three rings).

On the plus side, it is large. Its core are 4 pages, plus spellsheets and rp sheets it gets to 8. Its large size just works better than the wizard's tiny, hyper-condensed 1-page-with-everything. Do you need equipment? Here, have a neatly organised page with it. Do you need skills? here is the whole list, with some aid as to what synergies are there and other bonuses.

Finally it looks nice.

*Link*: [click here](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~marco.patrignani/About_Me_files/DND3.5-en-squera-sheet-melee.pdf)

*Second link*: [there is also a version for casters!](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~marco.patrignani/About_Me_files/DND3.5-en-squera-sheet-caster.pdf)

Comment: Would suggesting that the easy way to get a LaTeX version would be to make a post on Tex.SE saying "this document can only be made in a word processor" be overly cynical?  (Thinking in terms of how often "how do I make <something complicated> in latex" bubbles up to the hot question list and the general latex and do everything better than word attitude on that site.)

Answer (score 10):

## D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder

This character sheet doesn’t come in “blank” versions so I have to show an example character. Say hi to Vance from a Pathfinder game I was in.

[image: Thumbnail of Vance Highwind character sheet]

[Link to example character sheet](http://dragoonwraith.com/dnd/sheet/VanceHighwind/)

### How it was made

The sheet is a webpage written in PHP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. To create a new character, I just copy the code and edit it as appropriate; there is no “user-friendly” version that can be edited through a web-page for example.

### What makes it great

That said, the sheet is extremely feature-complete. I have written code to handle all sorts of different types of magic, which can be plugged in as I like. It handles arbitrary amounts of multiclassing, and does all the math for me.

I also really like that it puts the character’s backstory right there next to all his stats. Typical web-based character sheets put it at the bottom of the page, which is annoying when you’re looking for exactly that.

But if those were all it did, it would just be a customized version of any typical web-based character sheet, with a bit more flexibility because I’ve written up versions for so many different classes.

But the really important, “killer” features are what it does for you. I mentioned that it does the math for me. What I mean is that it keeps track of, and displays, each and every bonus, its source and type, and applies accurate bonus stacking rules, to every single number on the page. Simply hovering over any number that has a bonus applied to it results in a tooltip detailing all the bonuses. For example:

[image: Close-up of the bonuses to AC tooltip]

In addition, the sheet has the full text of each option that I use, for reference purposes, but hidden away until the option is clicked on. For example, when I click on my *encouraging roar* maneuver, I see this:

[image: Close-up of expanded maneuver]

These two features make it massively easier to keep track of everything going on with a character, and provide excellent sanity-checking on combining different features, both in terms of doing the math for you and keeping all the text nearby.

Answer (score 7):

### A New Dusk

This character sheet was made for my [fan-adaptation](http://www.crafty-games.com/forum/index.php?topic=6148) of the Mistborn Adventure Game for Alloy of Law. It is meant to evoke a more Wild West theme than the [original character sheet](http://www.crafty-games.com/files/File/Mistborn_Character_Sheet-v2.pdf).

[image: sheet]

[Link.pdf](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/GameDesignProducts/NewDuskCharacterSheet.pdf)

#### How it was made:

I took out the big guns for this one, it was made in Adobe Indesign.
One of the tricks for InDesign is that to do form lines, use [tab leaders](http://indesignsecrets.com/laying-out-basic-non-pdf-forms-using-tabs.php).
The main text logo in the corner was done with the Bleeding Cowboys font, however I edited the N by hand.

It occurs to me that the Occupation field in the fluff area is unrequired, as there is a Profession trait. Possibly this should be changed to a Union field. Labor Unions could be a big deal in this setting.

#### Style differences from the original:

I changed from Sanserif to serif, and from all-caps to small-caps
Boxes got these little indents in the corners.
The grey bubbles in around the section titles are less rounded (I think they could be changed to be boxes, with the indents.)
It has the same bug that v1 of the original character sheet had, with the names of "attributes" in plural, and "standing" and "resilience" in singular.

#### Why It is great.

I like the way it looks,
but the thing that clinches it for me, is the Experience Point cost for Advancement,
and the Character Creation costs in the bottom.
I stole the idea from the nWoD character sheets.
It is super useful for oneshots, and it is just so convenient.

Comment: I've been trying to recreate the form lines with scribus on Linux with no success. I might have to switch to InDesign.

Comment: mhhmm last time I used scribus it felt like the project was immature. It feel like it was reaching for Ms-Publisher (and not quiet getting there). Where as InDesign is in a league of its own.
If you get started on indesign, and can't work out how to do tab-leaders give me a poke, and I can send you the raw indesign file for this.

Comment: It seems that not being able to underline tabs has been a recognised bug in Scribus for two years. Sigh.

Answer (score 7):

### Ars Magica 5

This is a character sheet I made for Ars Magica 5 in the stock Mythic Europe setting.  It was modified from a similar set of sheets that I made for Ars Magica 4-based campaigns with alternate settings and abilities.

[image: Ars Magica 5 Character Sheet]

[PDF Here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZAoc8nWy-yZUJ1T291TDhYR00/edit?usp=sharing)

### How it was made:

I used a number of different versions of CorelDRAW!.  This sheet is basically a bunch of heavily formatted paragraph text boxes with lines and transparent rectangles separating the sections.  The "Ars Magica" header is simply text in *Engravers Old English* font with a 3d extrusion applied.

The Abilities block is also a Paragraph Text block, but with two columns so that I can add an ability in the appropriate section and the remaining abilities will simply move down and across to the next column without having to re-write the whole thing - which is very important when I make up custom campaign settings with quite different ability sets.

### Why it is good.

The [stock Ars Magica 5 character sheet](http://www.atlas-games.com/pdf_storage/arm5charsheet.pdf) doesn't have ability names pre-written in, and my fellow players and I found it immensely frustrating to have to copy down the same ability names over and *over* again, and by including ability names, I could also include reference to what *sort* of ability each was by the expedient of separating them by colour, and I could include reference to those abilities which have a penalty for zero-experience use.  Everything needed is present here without having to write it down each time, which saves a lot of time, improves readability, and immunizes the sheet against inadvertent eraser application (since we typically use pencil for everything).  There is far less wasted space than in the stock sheet (unless you count unused abilities).

Print it on parchment paper and it would look even more medieval, though in my experience, cheap parchment paper can't stand up to repeated erasing without the colour wearing off and showing its white core.

I used *Times* font mainly for its compactness and readability; more medieval blackletter-style fonts tend to be much wider and difficult to read at small font sizes.

If anyone is interested, I could post a character sheet from my Ars-4-based "Cyradia" campaign (which is based in a setting which features a magical/technological crossover with interstellar travel), though there are only cosmetic changes between this sheet and the Cyradia sheet.

Comment: I really like the use of colour on the skill list.

Answer (score 6):

### Dead Winter RPG

Dead Winter is my newest child. It is a system that I built from scratch, complete with its own setting, deities, races, classes and all that goodness that every d20 system should have. While it is "kinda" compatible with Pathfinder, it have a completly different number range, power level and overall feel. So, while the Pathfinder sheet works, it doesn't really get everything ya need to run the game.

**The Sheet:**

[image: My Custon DWRPG Character Sheet]

**How it was made:**

This character sheet is the translated version from pt-BR to en-US. I took the masochistic way and built it on Word. (Yep. That Microsoft Word). The logo looks a bit off - something on the PDF to PNG went wrong and it ended looking... weird. The rigth border of the front page got a bit cut - I will upload a better image when I get on my rig tomorrow.

**Why it is great:**

This sheet have everything that you would ever need! It have more slots for the bigger number of feats from a DWRPG game, the new skills already on the sheet, and the most important change on the combat rules right on the first page: The Armor Stack (More details below).

Also, the spellcasting section goes up to 10, which is normally not found on most d20 sheets but essential to DWRPG.

**How it differs from a normal Pathfinder sheet?**

On my DWRPG, there are a few different mechanics that need more detailed numbers. The system is more simulationist than normal D&D/PF, so a bit more of number crunch was added to support this paradigm.

- **The Armor Stack**: The Armor Stack is a area to help calculations to determine where a given attack landed if it missed. Did the attack miss because you dodged, parried, blocked with your shield? Or it was your armor that stopped the incoming attack? All of that is calculated with the Armor Stack.
- **Racial Features**: dedicated space to those things. Races have a bunch more of things that differentiate one from another, and all of that stuff goes there.
- Dedicated space for **Crit Threshold, Parry and Advantage**.
- A few extra fields to specialized stuff.
- It is ***blue***. Really, it raises the coolness factor up to eleven.

Answer (score 5):

### Primarchs Diceless

For a friends adaptation of Amber Diceless, to play Warhammer 40K Primarchs in the days of the Horus Heresy.

[image: Sheet Image]

[view .pdf here](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/GameDesignProducts/PrimarchsDicelessCharacterSheet.pdf)

#### How it was made.

It was made in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/), vector graphics editor.
It was based off the [Amber Diceless Character sheet](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/RPG/Amber_-_Diceless_RPG_csheet.pdf) 
A early draft can be [found here](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/GameDesignProducts/draft_Primarchs.svg)

I found that while Inkscape was good, lining things up was nontrivial.
Learning to use Guides is a must.
However there arn't any convenient ways I have seen to position guides at fractions of the page width (perhaps editing the SVG by hand might work).
One trick in Inkscape is that don't try and draw flat lines using the Underscore (_) as it won't line up with non-monospaced fonts.
Instead draw lines (to guides)

#### What is good about it.

After I showed the draft to the GM, I changed the font to use something more like the WH40K rule books: Casablanca Antique. I feel this really helped get the feel right.

I think the layout is really nice. It has a progression down to more mechanical:
Out of character right at the top (Phone is a reference to the Amber Diceless Sheet).
Then fluffy descriptive stuff,  then stats right in the middle, followed by spaces to write in all your abilities.
(Rather than the Amber, having a check box for every ability, space gave freedom to creae new ones.)
Right at the bottom is experience, which is a bit of a convention. In Amber system bad stuff is negative experience (if you go into XP debt basically)
It is probably going to get a revision to change Experience to Good Stuff, as these a the same thing in the Amber system. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

## WFRP 1e

The Sheet
[image]

[Link to the sheet template](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1sBdQMxXE2i0ztXD07K47-9kbQBRAEQ2UQ02aN5RyNJk/edit)

### How it was made

I made the sheet in Google Draw. I took the image of armor locations from a WFRP website. It was surprisingly easy to create and has been very useful. It looks best on a tablet.

### Why it's great

I will never lose my char sheet again. It's saved on google drive, and accessible on computer or tablet. It's easy to read, easy to navigate, and easy to update.  It's also the only WFRP 1e editable character sheet online that I know of.

Answer (score 5):

### L5R  (database character sheet)

[image: Screenshot]

[Full res screen-shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWpvN.png)

You may [download the MS-Access database here](http://oxinabox.ucc.asn.au/files/GameDesignProducts/l5r_db.zip), it is prefilled in with some example npcs from the campaign it was used in.
It is released under the MIT Licence.

This is not just a character sheet, it is a database designed as a GM note keeping tool.
It was mean to be small and simple, but it grew.
I didn't make it for myself but for a friend,
and thus I basically had a client.
Clients tend to make enhancement requests that each seem so simple and such a good idea.
It was based of a (vastly simpler) database I made for a game a ran witha similar premise.

When your PCs are Faction leaders it is good to be able to create a Report of all there faction members. Such a game also tends to have very large numbers of names reoccurring NPCs, that must be tracked.

#### How was it made

I made this in MS-Access 2007 (It has been tested to work in 2010, I assume it works on all later versions.)  It contains several database tables: of locations, factions and NPCS. It also contains several database tables of Skills and Spells (I stole someone elses Excel list of skills and spells to populate it.). It also contains several Reports, and Forms. As well as a terifying amount of VBA code to make it work.
*Don't Do This*, well at least consider carefully before doing this. It is something i think almost every developer will try: "Oh they only need a database accessable by one person, on one computer? Sure, MS-Access." then you get some kind of feature request: "Well I guess that could be done with alittle VBA behind the form."
It snowballs.

Still the end product was cool, and it wasn't unfun to make.

#### What is cool about it:

- So all fields that can be auto-calculated are. Eg skill dicepool, armour TN, Insight Rank
- It automatically calculates wound levels. I always found calculating wound levels to be really annoying as a GM.
- You can select spells from a drop down menu and it fills in all the details you need.
- Similarly for skill masteries: when your skill is set to above the skill mastery level it fills in the skill mastery box. This is another thing that is annoying to do as a GM.
- it uses the Ring graphic. Which I find rather readable for L5R
- All the data is also available in other forms, a table of npcs, with what ever information you choose is listed below the character sheet for the currently selected on

However, alot of the things it helps you avoid having to handle by auto-calculating them are things you can normally handle by handwaving as a GM. Who cares what skills he has to have Insight 3? All that matters is he has the 3rd level school ability to make 2 attacks per turn.

Someone else has made another similar database for L5R, but without the character sheet front end. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/l5rcm/). I haven't tried it though.

Comment: If those 206 lines of VBA terrifies you, then you must be easily terrified by code.  One little Access database I'm working on has 16186, and that's not including the SQL-Server side code...

Comment: It is scary for three reasons: 1 VBA is a terrible language (if it was VB.net things would be much better. I would have actual data-structures), 2 It was never meant to be this way (it was ment to have none). 3 it does not feel like it is good. (mind you wrote that a while ago so I may be miss remembering)

Answer (score 1):

### White Box D&D System Hack

[image]

**How it was made**
I used google draw to make the sheet; lining up things was both easier and more difficult due to google draw's autoalign function.

**What is good about it**
For one, it's all black and white, so I can print off a bunch of these without draining the ink out of my printer for every character that dies.  For two, it has clear lines for writing equipment and weapons, with another column listed for the weight.  Thirdly, it has the title of my campaign on it, which is just spiffy.

Find the full size version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjaW9.jpg).