# Looking for a simple online RPG diary

Tags: tools, organization

when you play a campaign for years, you tend to forget a lot of things, like which NPC you met where and under which circumstances. My goal is to replace the handwritten diary of tabletop RPG sessions by some online tool, where the players can edit the progress and keep track of what happened.

I imagine the following:

1. online, with write access for all players
2. Similar to a Wiki, the diary would have pages for all (player and non-player) characters, locations, and maybe also for items.
3. Anyone can make notes about a scene in play. When the name of a character, location or item is used, the diary scene should automatically link to the respective pages, without the need to interrupt the writing flow to insert a link manually. Much like facebook does it for names.
4. The page for e.g. a character would automatically contain all scenes where the character's name was mentioned. The same is true for locations and items.

My research brought me to a thread about [useful tools for campaign notes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/267/what-tools-are-useful-to-organize-a-gms-campaign-notes), which mentions the tools [Scabard](http://www.scabard.com) and [Obsidian Portal](http://www.obsidianportal.com). Both go in the right direction, but lack the automatic linking.

Are you aware of a diary tool or wiki with automatic linking? I am not looking for GM tools to keep track of stats or loot, just a simple, hassle-free diary.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I suggest playing around at [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) and seeing if you can find something that meets your requirements.  Specifically, you *probably* want a wiki that supports [CamelCase](http://www.wikimatrix.org/wiki/feature:camelcase) auto-linking.

Comment: @vueltaconicarus - I'm the developer of Scabard and had been thinking of adding an auto-link feature. When I saw your question, I decided to implement it. Check out http://www.scabard.com/campaign/278/character/329 for an example. The links in the description field are generated automatically based on the names of the other pages in the campaign.

Answer (score 3):

**Tumblr**

Tumblr wasn't made for RPGs, but in this case it delivers .  You can create a tumblr for your campaign. With the "submit" feature turned on, players can send in their diary entries.  Instead of automatic linking, tagging articles with the appropriate characters, places, etc. can be done easily.

As far as having pages specifically for articles about a character, Tumblr can accomplish this in two ways:

1. You can click on a tag (for example, a character's name) and it will return all the pages with that tag.
2. You can have links at the top of your tumblr with accomplish the same thing. Clicking the character's name would return everything with that tag. This would require fiddling with templates, but isn't very complicated.

Other benefits: Tumblr is a common platform that many people already know how to use.  There is a web app, but also mobile apps that could easily be used at the table.

Answer (score -2):

I use [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info) for that.

I can give [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/) access to all my players and they are all technically savey enough to use an editor and [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/) handles conflicts and merges well enough and work in a distributed manner. Note that [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/) works pretty much on all modern OSes and some not so modern ones.

The automatic linking will need a script written buy yourself: search for these words, replace with that pattern. [Awk](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) would work nicely for this. I do not believe there is such an automatic tool out of the box: how would it know which words are links and which are not?